A branch in git doesn't remove
I get a list from current branches, and fix_url_of_images branch doesn't in list.
but it is in checkout autocompletion list.
How can I delete fix_url_of_images?
[hasan@debian ~/Desktop/programming/The-Art-Of-Readable-Code-Persian-main]$ git branch 
* master
[hasan@debian ~/Desktop/programming/The-Art-Of-Readable-Code-Persian-main]$ git checkout 
FETCH_HEAD                 ORIG_HEAD 
fix_url_of_images          origin/fix_url_of_images 
HEAD                       origin/master 
master                     



what do you get for git status? Do you have uncommitted code, or similar, in the master branch?

Don't forget to delete the tag from your origin remote as well or the reference will still remain in checkouts.  git branch -D origin/fix_url_of_images as well as git branch -D fix_url_of_images will nuke both references.

Debian is not Ubuntu, git checkout autocomplete does not meant that you have the branch. The branch is probably still in the origin. Find the answer in the git-scm pages
